# Android Game - Code examples and Tips

Tags: android, open-source, game-engine

I have started learning Android App development and would now like to try myself on an Android game. I am entirely new to game-development however, and thus I have a lot of questions.

I was wondering if someone knew some well coded open source games for me to do some code-reviewing on to get myself in to this a little. I have gotten the experience that I learn fairly quickly if I have a chance to see good examples.

Additionally if someone has any good tips and information on the subject of using engines, I am open ear for those. I have no idea on if / which engine to use, if it makes sense or if it is easier to do everything myself. I am open for suggestions.

Thanks a lot!
- Cheers

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Are you new to Android Development as well? If yes, I don't recommend starting off by coding a game.
Just try to develop some simple Android apps first.

If no,

Here is a very populair game engine [AndEngine](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngine) [with some examples as well](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples)

If you want more examples of AndEngine, their are enough books about AndEngine.
To be very honnest, I don't think that any great game will share the source code because, sadly, there are people that will copy the code and adjust 2 or 3 things and call it their own.
Here is a little secret: Flappy Bird runs with AndEngine as well!

Comment: Thanks a lot! No I am not entirely new, I did try myself on some simple apps before. The thing is that i have never done anything graphically, those apps all used simple Android views with a layout.xml, so nothing fancy. I am willing to try something in a different direction, hence the game.

Comment: @Phil Nice! Goodluck with AndEngine! I'd like to check the game once it is finished!